# 0x swap quote gives "gas estimation failed error" on ropsten testnet even though I have enough funds

Tags: blockchain, ropsten, 0x

I'm using 0x swap quote api to convert my WETH -> UNI token. 0x swap quote gives "gas estimation failed error" on ropsten testnet even though I have enough funds.

The 0x swap price gives the gas estimation as 111000 wei and I have around 1.5 ropstenETH. So I don't understand why this error shows up. Isn't the gas estimate by 0x swap price api accurate enough? How much ropstenETH should I aim to have for this to work?

Attaching the code for reference:

```
const params = {
    sellToken: currentTrade.from.address,
    buyToken: currentTrade.to.address,
    sellAmount: amount,
    takerAddress: account,
  };

  // Fetch the swap quote.
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://ropsten.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?${qs.stringify(params)}`
  );
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Try this [solution](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/125873/asking-for-a-quote-for-non-eth-tokens-leads-to-gas-limit-error)

From the code, I presume you're running the [Road To Web3 Code](https://github.com/0xProject/swap-demo-tutorial) example.

This error usually happens if `takerAddress` does not have the funds that are intended to be traded or allowances set up to make the trade.

A couple things to check:

- Have you updated the CoinGecko List to pull Ropsten tokens ([the default](https://github.com/0xProject/swap-demo-tutorial/blob/main/swap-demo-tutorial-part-9/index.js#L15) is Mainnet tokens)? If not updated, the quote will be using incorrect addresses and expecting that the account has different tokens
- Can you double-check that the `takeraddress` does have the token to be traded (WETH)? WETH and RopstenETH are two different tokens; ETH does not conform to the ERC-20 standard (https://weth.io/).
- Check that the token allowance for WETH set properly